# JSON live search. Result items onclick events not firing. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

The code below works up to the point where I want the user to click on the link list item. For some reason my on click event handler is not catching it at all.

What am I missing? Really frustrated...

I have the following json file **data.json** with the following structure.

I **search this json** of **key value pairs** and **create a ul** with **links in it** as the result matches.

**Each result inside ul** is a link with **an href**.

I already generate these dynamically.

I would like to **capture this click**, do a **e.preventDefault()** on it, then **get the href attribute value** and **windows.location to it**. This keeps a native html5 safari ap from opening in a new window as I request a different page.

Here's the [LIVE DEMO](http://nexlevel.org/v94/)

```js
[
  {
    "name":"Sarah Connor",
    "client_id":"111"
  },
  {
    "name":"John Travolta",
    "client_id":"222"
  },
  {
    "name":"Tom Cruise",
    "client_id":"333"
  }
]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!--Import materialize.css-->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12">
<input id="search" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="at least 1 character...">
<label for="search">Search</label>
<div id="results" style="position: absolute; top:48px; background: white;"></div>
</div>

</div>

</div>
<!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script>

$( ".collection-item" ).on("click", "a", function(e) {
console.log('test click event fired.');

});


$(document).ready(function() {


$('#search').keyup(function(){

// the search input
var searchField = $('#search').val();

// if at least one char is typed...
if (searchField.length > 0) {

// A. Empty results div.
$('#results').empty();

// "i" = ignore case
var regex = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');

var output = '<ul class=\"collection\">';

// get JSON from PHP...
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {

// loop through JSON array of key/value pairs...
$.each(data, function(key, val){

// Returns a Number, representing the position of the first occurrence 
// of the specified searchvalue, or -1 if no match is found

// Here we search and compare against the -1 condition.
// Example... val.name.search(regex) different than NOT FOUND...

// If we got a match on name OR client_id....
if ((val.name.search(regex) != -1)) {

output += '<a href=\"#random\" class=\"collection-item\">';
output += val.name;
output += '<span class=\"badge\">' + val.client_id + '</span>';
output += '</a>';
console.log('match!');

}
// end if

});
// end each

output += '</ul>';
// close ul tag

// output to results div
$('#results').html(output);

}); 


} else {

// clear results div
$('#results').empty();

}

});
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should ask questions which clearly define your problem - ie isolate the problem within your code. this will eliminate any confusion regarding what is causing unexpected behaviour and you will often solve the problem for yourself during this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to apply the event listener before the elements exist

move your event listener assignment to after you iterate over your results, and the elements are added to the dom.

Also, I believe your event assignment syntax is incorrect. you need to select the element in the `$(..)` part (ie include your `a` here) and then apply the handler. You seem to have an extra incorrect parameter ("a") in that part, which I've moved into the selection part.

ie :

```
$('#results').html(output);

...

$( "a.collection-item" ).on("click", function(e) {
console.log('test click event fired.');

});
```

Comment: Because it's generated or not as the user types in search box. How do I add events to the results that I generate?

Comment: Console still does not show an event was bound to it. So crazy.. It does show for the keyUp which is unrelated..

Comment: add debug to test that the selection is finding the elements: `console.log("items: ", $("a.collection-item"));`

Comment: what if I add an onclick on the a tag.

Comment: `output += '<a href=\"#!\" class=\"collection-item\" onlick="">';`

Comment: what i've suggested works. here's a demo. i suspect you have other issues https://jsfiddle.net/Lyvgeva2/6/

Comment: Can you apply your jsfiddle example to my example?

Comment: i suggest using a good debugger (like chrome) and stepping through your code to see what part is not working as expected. I can see no good reason why it wouldn't work. also add as much debugging as you can imagine, until you solve your problem, as i suggested, debug that the elements exist in the dom as you expect, if they don't `$(...)` will return an empty set. also debug that this line is being reached.

Answer (score 0):

**Modified**

Added `onclick=\"js_redirect(this, event)\`

```
// If we got a match on name OR client_id....
if ((val.name.search(regex) != -1)) {

output += '<a href=\"#!\" class=\"collection-item\" onclick=\"js_redirect(this, event)\">';
output += val.name;
output += '<span class=\"badge\">' + val.client_id + '</span>';
output += '</a>';
console.log('match!');

}
// end if
```

**Added function**

```
function js_redirect(el, event) {

// Prevent the actual link redirect
event.preventDefault();

// Got to href location via Script instead.
window.location = el.href;

}
```

Comment: this is generally considered bad practice. sure it works (and always has) but modern approaches steer away from this for many good reasons. mostly because your function (js_redirect) has to be in the global namespace.

Comment: Alright. It appears that my search box is inside of a tab component. I wonder if this is what’s affecting it. I’ll give it a try soon.